# Como saber qual usuário criou uma tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Não encontrei na seção 'Tags' algo que me informasse sobre quem foi o criador de uma tag.
Há como saber quais tags eu criei ou qual foi o usuário que criou uma tag?

Comment: Procurei por algo do tipo no [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) e não encontrei nada...

Comment: Vendo [esta questão](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created) no meta inglês, parece não haver meio.

Comment: Qual a utilidade de se conhecer o autor de uma tag?

Comment: Por curiosidade mesmo. A medalha "Taxonomista" é concedida quando uma tag que você criou é utilizada em 50 perguntas. Gostaria de saber as tags que criei para saber o quão longe estou desta melhada =)